# Unable to locate an element in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My question is regarding locating a web element(a browse button) in a webpage in order to upload a file using Selenium(Java), but when my control is switching to that particular window which contains the browse button none of the elements are getting located. I am sharing the HTML code used to locate the browse button along with my script written in java(using eclipse software).The error that I am getting is "No such element exception". Please let me know if you need any further details regarding the issue. I am actually opening the "checkin files" window by clicking a link "Add New File" but the problem is the control is not passing to this window.

Following is the Java code:

```
//Step 5: Click the Browse Button
for(String browseWindowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
    driver.switchTo().window(browseWindowHandle);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement clickBrowseButton=driver.findElement(By.name("bfile0"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(clickBrowseButton));
    clickBrowseButton.click();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\tnag\\Desktop\\FileUpload.exe");
//Step 5: Click the Done button in the File Upload window
WebElement addNewFileDone=
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"));
    addNewFileDone.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("addNewFileDone");       
    }
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGVLV.png)

Comment: I do not see `input` tags being closed. Can you try by closing them in your html code?
Also, you have to post code in the question rather referencing them from the pastebins so that it helps community members to debug easily.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help you to some extent

Comment: Hi, thanks for the questions. This are the kind which surly can be tackled here. But please make a few changes to your question: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask    just include the code and the screenshot here without link. Also add the exception (stack-trace).

Comment: Thanks for your response.Could you please mention about the input tag I did not get that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to your Question-

You need to take care of a couple of things here as:

1. Much of the code block below `Click the Browse Button` comment is not in use.
2. You have initiated a `for` loop but haven't structured it. You may like to remove it completely.
3. `driver.manage().window().maximize();` should have been in your code much earlier while you first access the URL. So you may like to remove it.
4. While you do `WebElement clickBrowseButton = driver.(...);` ensure that the `name` locator identifies the Browse Button uniquely.
5. Next `isDisplayed()` is no more necessary so you may like to remove it.
6. `clickBrowseButton.click();` should do it all, opening the Windows File Selector.
7. In case you have passed all the references of the dialogebox to AutoIT properly `Runtime.getRuntime.exec(...)` would pass the file for sure.
8. Depending upon your Web App design you may require to click on `Upload` button.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code actually the issue that I am facing is that the control is not getting switched to the checkin file window due to which I am not able to click the browse button.

Comment: @titli0216 As I mentioned if you take care of the points 1-6 mentioned above, your Selenium-Java part would be perfecto. But in your case point no 7 is crucial to get the path set by AutoIT. You may need to revisit the AutoIT settings. Can you consider to Accept my Answer as a Solution to your Question? Thanks.

Comment: @titli0216 Glad to be able to help you :) When I reviewed your code it was in an attachment

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable suggestions actually I found the root cause why the web element was not getting invoked it was because i missed switching to an iframe which is why my autoIT script was not getting called. The issue got resolved. Thanks all for the help. This platform is really helpful.